# Parsing text file using python for list of ID's

Tags: python, regex, parsing, text

I have downloaded a large amount of data and stored it in text files. I also have an overview document. An example can be seen here:

```
Without x terms:0
ID's: 

Without y terms: 15
ID's: 10362383
10390455
10658293
10658295
10868884
10947144
11015024
11430394
11674903
11773985
7762512
7934452
8879328
9186393
9812933
```

I need to loop through the ID's without y terms, however I am unsure how to parse the text file to get those ID's. So far I have written this, but am unsure how to proceed.

```
file = '...'
file_object = open(file, 'r')
text = file_object.read()
print (text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path_file = '...'
f = open(path_file, 'r').read()
ids_string = f.split("Without y terms:")[1].split("ID's:")[1].split()
ids_integer = [int(e) for e in ids_string]
print (ids_integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse through each line in the file. You must create a for-each loop:

`for each line in file:`

This will divide the file up by the line and should loop through the ID's without y terms. Keep in mind that this will also split up the top portion of the file (non y terms).